# How to filter data with the hilbert transform?

Tags: python, scipy

how can I use the Hilbert transform in python to filter data?? My data are recorded with 250Hz and I wanna filter these with 6-11Hz. 
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there something wrong with the online docs for scipy.signal.hilbert and scipy.fftpack.hilbert?

Comment: No there is nothing wrong but I don´t know how to use scipy.signal.hilbert or scipy.fftpack.hilbert to filter data and I can´t find this information...

Comment: Why do you need a Hilbert transform to filter your data? Doesn't a simple FFT filter suffice?